# Accept-Encoding: lzf - Browser compatibility list?

Tags: browser-support, content-encoding

Per the title, I'm looking for a browser capability list for `Accept-Encoding: lzf` - I'd like to use `lzf` encoding but I'm not which browsers support it and couldn't find a list. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any browsers support LZF transfer compression at this point.  I say this because searching for "lzf firefox", "lzf safari", "lzf internet explorer" and "lzf chrome" don't yield any documents about their implementations of it.

The only relevant result appears to be a JavaScript library that implements LZF: https://github.com/pkalogiros/LZFjs   However, there is no way that would enable transfer encoding unless it were built into the browsers.